# understanding C macros when they are inside some conditional statements like switch/if/esle

Tags: c, macros

As you can see from the code that i have a `switch` statement and here inside each separate `switch` branch I'm defining a macro. and in later part of the code, based upon these macros I'm printing some ouput to terminal. So in this scenario what would be the output of the below code?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() 
    {
        // k integer to hold user input
        int k;
        
        scanf("%d",&k); // capture input here

        switch(k)
        {
            case 1 :
            #define first_case
            break;
            case 2 :
             #define second_case
            break;
            case 3 :    
             #define third_case
            break;
            case 4 : 
            #define fourth_case
            break;
        }
        
    
 #ifdef first_case
        printf(" first_case\n");
  #endif

  #ifdef second_case
        printf(" second_case\n");
  #endif
        
  #ifdef third_case
        printf(" third_case\n");
 #endif

   #ifdef fourth_case
        printf(" fourth_case\n");
 #endif
    
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand what preprocessor macros are. I suggest to start reading your C textbook.

Comment: The preprocessor is a pure compile-time thing. It doesn't do anything at run-time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because not understanding fundamental syntax of the language does not make for a useful question or demonstrate the level of background research expected.

Comment: To understand how macros are evaluated, add `-E` to the compiler command line to see what the preprocessor outputs, i.e. what the compiler actually compiles.

Comment: Please, compile your code with `-E` e.g. `gcc -E myfile.c` and have a look at the output. It's exactly what the C compiler "sees" as `-E` forces a "pre-processor only" compile.

Comment: The #define is  pre processor statement. i.e, when the compiler peruses through the code, it looks for these statements first. All your #define statements are processed before the rest of the code. Use #if/#ifdef if you want conditional macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros (`#define MACRO ...`) are processed by the C preprocessor *before* the actuel compile process takes place.

So the compiler only "sees" this once the file has been preprocessed:

```
int main()
{
  // your code goes here
  int k = 0;

  scanf("%d", &k);
  switch (k)
  {
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
    break;
  case 3:
    break;
  case 4:
    break;
  }

  printf("typed first_case\n");
  printf("typed second_case\n");
  printf("typed third_case\n");
  printf("typed fourth_case\n");
}
```

You could write your program like this, and the outcome would be exactly the same:

```
#define first_case
#define second_case
#define third_case
#define fourth_case

/* Find the longest line among the giving inputs and print it */

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  // your code goes here
  int k = 0;

  scanf("%d", &k);
  switch (k)
  {
  case 1:
    printf("case 1\n");
    break;
  case 2:
    break;
  case 3:
    break;
  case 4:
    break;
  }


#ifdef first_case
  printf("typed first_case\n");
#endif
#ifdef second_case
  printf("typed second_case\n");
#endif

#ifdef third_case
  printf("typed third_case\n");
#endif
#ifdef fourth_case
  printf("typed fourth_case\n");
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a preprocessor macro cannot be set or altered at runtime, you just need an ordinary automatic variable.  For example:

```
int k=0;
int first_case = 0;   // 0 resolves to False
int second_case = 0;  // 0 resolves to False
int third_case = 0;   // 0 resolves to False
int fourth_case = 0;  // 0 resolves to False

scanf("%d",&k);
switch(k)
{   
    case 1 :
        printf("case 1\n");
        first_case = 1;
        break;
    case 2 :
        second_case = 1;
        break;
    case 3 :  
        third_case = 1;
        break;
    case 4 :
        fourth_case = 1;
        break;
}

if (first_case)
    printf("typed first_case\n");

if (second_case)
    printf("typed second_case\n");

if (third_case)
    printf("typed third_case\n");

if (fourth_case)
    printf("typed fourth_case\n");
```

Having said that, you are doing the same test twice, so most would just use the `case`, probably with a `default`:

```
scanf("%d",&k);
switch(k)
{   
    case 1 :
        printf("typed first_case\n");
        break;
    case 2 :
        printf("typed second_case\n");
        break;  
    case 3 :    
        printf("typed third_case\n");
        break;
    case 4 : 
        printf("typed fourth_case\n");
        break;
    default :
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid response: %d\n", k);
}
```